# ORACLE APEX Report Templates not showing up

Tags: oracle, templates, oracle-apex

When I try to make a Classic Report with a Card Template, the Template Is not showing up in the right window. I don’t have Media Lists either for example. But things like Blank with attributes are there.
Does anyone know a solution for this?
Greets

Comment: what is the version of apex ?

Comment: The latest version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different templates. Every region has its own template - that is the "Region Template". "Blank with attributes" is one of those templates, by default it will be "Standard".

If your region is of type "Classic Report" you will get the option to select an report template for the report itself. That can be selected in the "Appearance" section of the report attributes. This is where you can find templates like "Card Template".

[image]

Comment: Exactly, but in the template option there are some but not cards or media lists

Comment: When I go to the report region -> appearance -> template it‘s showing up templates like Alert, Blank with Attributes, Buttons Container, Content Block, Inline Popup, Inline Dialog etc. but not the Cards template.

Comment: Check the image - I updated my answer. You need to look under Report Attributes, not Region Attributes

Comment: Thanks man, it actually worked. I would‘ve never had the idea of checking the Attribute part of the report region. Big up

Answer (score 0):

The way you described it, "solution" is to upgrade your Apex version as it seems that yours doesn't support templates you described.